# grails oauth2 provider plugin not working as expected

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have been trying to configure the oauth2 provider plugin in my grails application, but I am facing certain issues, and other than the plugin documentation, I didn't find any other sources that could help.

I have followed all the stepd mentioned in the doc, and made changes in Config.groovy

Now hitting localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-client&scope=read should redirect me to login page which it does.
After login however, I want authorization window to appear where user accepts or rejects granting authorization. I am however just getting a JSON result:

{"url":"http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-client&scope=read","success":true}

Why am I not getting an authorization prompt instead? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I have made some changes:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
'cookieSessionFilter',
'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter','logoutFilter',
'authenticationProcessingFilter','exceptionTranslationFilter', 'oauth2ProviderFilter', 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter',
'oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter', 'securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter',
'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter','anonymousAuthenticationFilter', 'oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor'
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [

'/oauth/token': 'JOINED_FILTERS, -cookieSessionFilter, -oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter' ,

'/securedOAuth2Resources/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-cookieSessionFilter, -securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',

'/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter'

]

Just proper ordering of filters seems to be solving the problem.
With this configuration I am able to generate the access_token.